# Non-degenerate quadratic forms have zero kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, we say $Q:V\to F$ is a quadratic form if

1. $Q(\lambda v)=\lambda^2Q(v)$, and
2. the map $B:V\times V\to F$ defined by $B(u,v)=Q(u+v)-Q(u)-Q(v)$ is bilinear

I'd like to show that if $B$ is non-degenerate, then $\{x\in V\mid Q(x)=0\}=\{0\}$, but I'm kind of stuck. The problem is that $B$ is not necessarily an inner product.

Note: The bilinear map $B$ is called non-degenerate if $B(u,V)=0\implies u=0$

Comment: It's not true..

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you have a counter example?

Comment: Note that an [Isotropic quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form) is not the same as a degenerate quadratic form. It is true over odd characteristics that $B$ non-degenerate implies $Q$ non-degenerate.

Comment: @Kolja Actually it is not true over odd characteristic neither, just take the field of order 3 for the counter example you gave below.

Comment: @SidCaroline No, I said $B$ non-degenerate implies $Q$ non-degenerate. Being a non-degenerate quadratic form is not the same as $Q(x)=0 \: \rightarrow x=0$. The other condition can be said as '$Q$ doesn't represent $0$'. For example $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2-y^2$ are both non degenerate quadratic forms over $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the first one doesn't represent zero, while the second one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V=\mathbb{F}^2$, $Q(\vec{x})=x_1x_2$, $B(\vec{x},\vec{y})=x_1y_2+x_2y_1$ is a counterexample, where $\vec{x}= {{x_1}\choose{x_2}}, \vec{y}= {{y_1}\choose{y_2}}.$

Answer (score 1):

On $\mathbf C$ considered as an $\mathbf R$-vector space, the *standard inner product* $z\cdot z'=xx'+yy'$  ($z=x+iy$, $z'=x'+iy'$) is non-degenerate, but the set of vectors $\;z=t(1\pm i),\enspace t\in\mathbf R$, satisfy $q(z)=0$.

(The set of vectors $v$ such that $q(v)=0$  is called the *isotropic cone* of the bilinear form associated to the quadratic form)

It is the reason why on complex vector spaces, one uses hermitian forms.